# Calendar .ics to CSV in Python

Tags: python, calendar

The following code was working well until it found an event without the field description (not sure how that happened), is there a way to continue to the next event when errors are found in one event?

```
# ics to csv example
# dependency: https://pypi.org/project/vobject/

import vobject
import csv

with open('sample.csv', mode='w') as csv_out:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_out, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    csv_writer.writerow(['WHAT', 'WHO', 'FROM', 'TO', 'DESCRIPTION'])

    # read the data from the file
    data = open("sample.ics").read()

    # iterate through the contents
    for cal in vobject.readComponents(data):
        for component in cal.components():
            if component.name == "VEVENT":
                # write to csv
                csv_writer.writerow([component.summary.valueRepr(),component.attendee.valueRepr(),component.dtstart.valueRepr(),component.dtend.valueRepr(),component.description.valueRepr()])
```

This works as intended now. Thank you @stovfl

```
import vobject
import csv

with open('calendar2022.csv', mode='w') as csv_out:
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_out, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
csv_writer.writerow(['WHAT', 'FROM', 'TO', 'DESCRIPTION', 'LOCATION'])

    # read the data from the file
data = open("calendar.ics").read()

    # iterate through the contents
for cal in vobject.readComponents(data):
    for component in cal.components():
        if component.name == "VEVENT":
            writerow = []
            for attr in ['summary', 'dtstart', 'dtend', 'description', 'location']:
                if hasattr(component, attr):
                    writerow.append(getattr(component, attr).valueRepr())
                else:
                    writerow.append('Undefined!')

            print(writerow)
            csv_writer.writerow(writerow)
```

Comment: Have you looked into `try`?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Because I started learning very recently and am new to this can you explain how to include this statement?

Comment: This seems like a rather basic question, have you done any research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Question**: continue to the next event when errors are found in one event?

- [Live-Demo - repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/MerrySpiritedChief)
- [VObject](https://github.com/eventable/vobject)

  > VObject is intended to be a full-featured Python package for parsing and generating vCard and vCalendar files

---

Verify if `all` attributes exists in `'VENVENT'`, if not `break` and skip this `'VEVENT'` and continue.

```
      if component.name == "VEVENT":
          # write to csv

          # verify if all attr in component
          attr_list = ('summary', 'attendee', 'dtstart', 'dtend', 'description')

          if not all((hasattr(component, attr) for attr in attr_list)):
            break
```

Instead to skip the `VEVENT` and continue, replace the missing column with the value `Undefined!`

```
      if component.name == "VEVENT":
          # write to csv

          # aggregate column values
          writerow = []
          for attr in ['summary', 'attendee', 'dtstart', 'dtend', 'description']:

              if hasattr(component, attr):
                  writerow.append(getattr(component, attr).valueRepr())
              else:
                  writerow.append('Undefined!')

          print(writerow)
          # csv_writer.writerow(writerow)
```

Comment: I still continue to get this 'error.csv_writer.writerow([component.summary.valueRepr(),component.dtstart.valueRepr(),component.dtend.valueRepr(),component.description.valueRepr(),component.location.valueRepr()])
     26 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vobject/base.py in __getattr__(self, name)
    529                 return self.contents[toVName(name)][0]
    530         except KeyError:
--> 531             raise AttributeError(name)
    532 
    533     normal_attributes = ['contents', 'name', 'behavior', 'parentBehavior', 'group']

AttributeError: description'

Comment: @pyproper: You didn't follow my example. As long as you use `csv_writer.writerow([...,component.description.valueRepr(),...)` you will see this error.

Comment: I tried to uncomment `# csv_writer.writerow(writerow)` but it only prints the tablehead. I also tried the `print(writerow)` but it prints it not in a clean format. The code that I had in the beginning prints what I want very clean in a new csv but it still stops when it finds VEVENT without description atribute